# rsync with folder and file name pattern matching to copy files

Tags: terminal, rsync

Right now I'm successfully running:

```
rsync -uvma  --include="*/" --include="*.css" --exclude="*" $spec_dir $css_spec_dir
```

In a shell script which copies all of the files in the source directory, that are .css files, into a target directory.

I want to do the same for HTML files, but only where they are in a subfolder with the name 'template'.

So I'm in directory ~/foo, and I want to rsync where the --include="*/" only matches on subfolders with the name 'template'. So ~/foo/bar/template/baz/somefile.html would match, and so would ~foo/bar/baz/qux/template/someotherfile.html, but NOT ~/foo/bar/thirdfile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked:

```
rsync -uvma --include="*/" --include="templates/**.html"  --exclude="*" $html_all_dir $html_dir
```

My guess is, your format and mine probably accomplish the same thing. I know I tried about 20 different patterns before this one, and this is the only one that worked properly. I don't think I tried your format though :)

Answer (score 2):

Although it looks a little bit strange, this works for me:

```
rsync -uvma --include="*/" --include="*/template/*/*.html" --include="*/template/*.html" --include="template/*.html" --include="template/*/*.html" --exclude="*" $spec_dir $html_spec_dir
```

Comment: This was close to what ended up working, which was rsync -uvma --include="*/" --include="templates/**.html"  --exclude="*" $html_all_dir $html_dir

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me:

```
rsync -umva --include="**/templates/**/*.html" --exclude="*.html" source/ target
```

Were you looking for `**`? Here you have to be careful about choosing your exclude pattern, `*` won't work as it matches directories on the way. If rsync finds `foo/templates/some.html`, it will first copy `foo`, then `foo/templates` and then `foo/templates/some.html`, but before it gets there `*` already matched `foo` and nothing gets copied.